# Issue implement infinite scrolling using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling on my social networking site project using ajax, followed manual, but not working.

[image: Sceenshoot]

I have setup the following:

index.php

```
<?php
        include("includes/header.php");
        //session_destroy();//logout
        include("includes/classes/User.php");
        include("includes/classes/Post.php");

        if(isset($_POST['post'])){
            $post=new Post($con,$userLoggedIn);
            $post->submitPost($_POST['post_text'],'none');
        }
     ?>
        <div class="user_details column">
            <a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn ?>"><img src="<?php echo $user['profile_pic']; ?>"></a>
            <div class="user_details_left_right">
                <a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn ?>"><?php echo $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name'];?></a>
                <?php echo 'Posts:'.$user['num_posts']?>
                <br>
                <?php echo 'Likes:'.$user['num_likes']?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_column column">
            <form class="post_form" action="index.php" method="POST">
                <textarea name="post_text" placeholder="Got something to say?"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="post"id="post_button" value="Post">
            </form>
            <?php //ajax taking care of this part of loading post from line 37-60
            /*
                $post=new Post($con,$userLoggedIn);
                $post->loadPostFriends();
                */

             ?>
             <div class="posts_area" id="#posts_area"></div>
             <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="#loading">
        </div>
        <script>
            var userLoggedIn='<?php echo $userLoggedIn;?>';

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#loading').show();
                //original ajax request for loading first posts

                $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:"page=1&userLoggedIn="+userLoggedIn,
                    cache:false,

                    success: function(data){
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('.posts_area').html(data);
                    }

                });


            });

        </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax_load_posts.php

```
<?php 
include('../../config/config.php');
include('../classes/User.php');
include('../classes/Post.php');

$limit=10;//Number of posts to be loaded per call

//$posts=new Post($con, $_REQUEST['userLoggedIn']);
$post=new Post($con,$userLoggedIn);
//$posts->loadPostFriends();
$post->loadPostFriends();

 ?>
```

however direct call top the loadPostFriendIn() function works

```
<?php
$post=new Post($con,$userLoggedIn);
$post->loadPostFriends();
?>
```

Here are the other pages i have if needed:

Post.php

```
<?php
//For post something 
class Post{
    private $id_obj;
    private $con;

    public function __construct($con,$id){
        $this->con =$con;
        //$user_details_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
        $this->id_obj = new User($con, $id);

    }
    //we will use this constructor to create user object
    //demo code to use in other places
    //!user_ob= new User($con, $userLoggedIn) 
    //^object        ^class      ^available in the header file it returns id of logged in user
    public function submitPost($body,$user_to){
        $body=strip_tags($body);//remove html tags
        $body=mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con,$body);
        $check_empty=preg_replace('/\s+/','', $body);//delete all spaces before checking empty
        if($check_empty!=""){//if spaces are removed from a blak post the $check_empty will not have any valu. will be equal to "", != means it contains something in it.

            //Current date and time
            $date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            //Get username
            $added_by=$this->id_obj->getUserid();

            //if user is on own profile, user_to is 'none'
            if($user_to==$added_by){
                $user_to="none";
            }

            //insert post
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$body','$added_by','$user_to','$date_added','no','no','0')");

            $returned_id=mysqli_insert_id($this->con);
            //insert notification
            //update post count for user
            $num_posts=$this->id_obj->getNumPosts();
            $num_posts++;
            $update_query=mysqli_query($this->con,"UPDATE users SET num_posts='$num_posts' WHERE id='$added_by'");

        }

    }

    public function loadPostFriends(){
        $str="";//String to return
        $data=mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted='no' ORDER BY id DESC");

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
            $postid=$row['id'];
            $body=$row['body'];
            $added_by=$row['added_by'];
            $date_time=$row['date_added'];

            //Prepare user_to srting so it can be included even if not posted to a user
            if($row['user_to']=="none"){
                $user_to="";
            }
            else{
                $user_to_obj=User($con,$row['user_to']);
                $user_to_name=$user_to_obj -> getFirstAndLastName();
                $user_to="to <a href='".$row['user_to']."'>".$user_to_name."</a>";

            }
            //Check if user who posted, has theri account colosed
            $addes_by_obj=new User($this->con,$added_by);
            if($addes_by_obj->isClosed()){
                continue;
            }

            $user_details_query=mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM users WHERE id='$added_by'");
            $user_row=mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
            $first_name=$user_row['first_name'];
            $last_name=$user_row['last_name'];
            $profile_pic=$user_row['profile_pic'];



            //Timeframe
            $date_time_now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $start_date=new DateTime($date_time);//Time of post
            $end_date=new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
            $interval=$start_date->diff($end_date);
            if($interval->y>=1){
                if($interval==1)
                    $time_message=$interval->y." Year ago";//1 year ago
                else
                    $time_message=$interval->y." Years ago";//1+ year ago
            }
            else if($interval->m >= 1){
                if($interval->d==0){
                        $days=" ago";
                    }
                else if($interval -> d ==1){
                    $days=$interval->d." Day ago";
                }
                else{
                    $days=$interval->d." Days ago";
                }


                if($interval->m==1){
                    $time_message=$interval->m." Moth".$days;
                }
                else{
                    $time_message=$interval->m." Moths".$days; 
                }

            }
            else if($interval->d>=1){
                if($interval -> d ==1){
                    $time_message="Yesterday";
                }
                else{
                    $time_message=$interval->d." Days ago";
                }
            }
            else if($interval->h>=1){
                if($interval->h==1){
                    $time_message=$interval->h." Hour ago";
                }
                else{
                    $time_message=$interval->h." Hours ago";
                }

            }
            else if($interval->i>=1){
                if($interval->i==1){
                    $time_message=$interval->i." Minute ago";
                }
                else{
                    $time_message=$interval->i." Minutes ago";
                }

            }
            else{
                if($interval->s<30){
                    $time_message=" Just now";
                }
                else{
                    $time_message=$interval->s." Seconds ago";
                }

            }
            $str .= "<div class='status_post'>
                        <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                            <img src='$profile_pic' width='50'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='posted_by' style='color:#ACACAC;'>
                            <a href='added_by'>$first_name $last_name </a>$user_to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$time_message
                        </div>
                        <div id='post_body'>
                            $body
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    ";

        }
        echo $str;//it will load multiple posts
    }
}


 ?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
ob_start();//Turns on output buffering
session_start();

$timezone = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","social");//connection variable

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect:".mysqli_connect_errno();
}
?>
```

Comment: Not many people are going to shift through the entire code. You need to provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks @Joseph the tutorial you shared helped me understand ajax better.